# No method named X found for type *mut Y in the current scope

Tags: rust

I want to call the method `a` on a struct `I`. I am told Rust can't find the method, but am unsure why:

```
error: no method named `a` found for type `*mut I` in the current scope

 --> src/lib.rs:7:16
  |
7 |     unsafe { i.a(5) }
  |                ^
```

This is a minimal reproducible example:

```
extern crate libc;
use self::libc::int32_t;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn i_a(i: *mut I) -> *mut int32_t {
    unsafe { i.a(5) } // error: no method named `a` found for type `*mut I` in the current scope
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct I {
    pub values: Vec<i32>,
}

impl I {
    pub fn a(&self, n: i32) -> i32 {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Dereferencing pointers, unlike references, is not implicit. You have to dereference that pointer.

Comment: side-note: your `i_a` function returns `*mut int32_t` while the `a` method returns `i32`, even if you fix your issue, the types won't match up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's remove the extern C stuff, it is not useful here:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct I {
    pub values: Vec<i32>,
}

impl I {
    pub fn a(&self, n: i32) -> i32 {
        return 0;
    }
}

pub fn i_a(i: *mut I) -> i32 {
    unsafe { i.a(5) }
}
```

The issue is that pointers in Rust are *extremely* limited: they only have the methods implemented on [the primitive pointer type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html).

Basically, you can check if a pointer is null, compare it for equality, perform some arithmetic and dereference it. Note that few operations are actually unsafe on a pointer (mostly arithmetic and dereference).

To actually use the *pointee*, you first need to dereference the pointer to obtain a reference from it; this is unsafe, but using the reference is then safe.

Thus you can rewrite `i_a` as either:

```
pub fn i_a(i: *mut I) -> i32 {
    unsafe { (*i).a(5) }
}
```

or:

```
pub fn i_a(i: *mut I) -> i32 {
    unsafe { &*i }.a(5)
}
```

and then it will work.

Comment: I'd expect people to blindly copy-paste your code, so I'd suggest adding the `NULL` check.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Well, if the pointer is null then it'll probably crash; which is the behavior you'll get if you pass any wild pointer anyway.

Comment: That response seems uncharacteristically *laissez faire* for you. Following that logic to the ridiculous end, it seems like many (all?) of the checks that Rust does are irrelevant because if you do it "wrong" it will be likely crash anyway.

Comment: @Shepmaster: It's just that I've seen too many newcomers think their code is safe because they have a null-pointer check, and then wonder why the debugger indicates `0x4` as the address of their object (C++). When dealing with `unsafe` code, I'd rather people seat down and think it through: can they have a null pointer here? If they can, what should the response be (ignore/crash/other)? If they cannot, maybe an `assert` (or `debug_assert`) should document this?

Comment: I don't think we should check for `nullptr` unless the interface specifically lists it as a possibility or as a way to express `Option::None`.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to call the method `a` on a struct `I`

The code does *not* have a struct I; it has a *mutable pointer* to a struct `I`.

I'd **strongly** recommend reading the [chapter on raw pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/raw-pointers.html) before doing any in-depth work with them. Rust is a great language and the compiler works very hard to prevent screw ups when you use the safe aspects; when you get into unsafe **you** need to know what you are doing because you have told the compiler to stand back and watch.

One specific difference between references and raw pointers is that raw pointers *may be `NULL`*. References, on the other hand, may *never be `NULL`*. That's one reason why it is required to use an `unsafe` block any time you dereference a raw pointer.

Normally, you [check for a `NULL` pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.is_null) and then convert it to a reference if it's not `NULL`:

```
let i = &*i;     // For `&T`
let i = &mut *i; // For `&mut T`
```

Now that you have a reference, you can call methods.

There are also helper functions like [`as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.as_ref):

```
pub extern "C" fn i_a(i: *mut I) -> int32_t {
    match unsafe { i.as_ref() } {
        Some(i) => i.a(5),
        None => 42,
    }
}
```

---

The code also has a giant hole waiting to be exploited. `i_a` purports to return a *pointer* to an integer, but the code returns an integer directly. That's a very bad mismatch

Answer (score 2):

The method `a` technically takes a `self: &I` argument (but the shorthand `&self` is more convenient). So the method expects a reference to an `I`. The variable `i` is of type `*mut I`, but a `&I` is expected. These types obviously do not match up. But you can either easily convert your `i` to a `&I` by dereferencing the raw pointer and immediately referencing it again (`(&*i).a(42)`). Alternatively you can implement the method for pointers:

```
trait A {
    fn a(self, n: i32) -> i32;
}

impl A for *mut I {
    fn a(self, n: i32) -> i32 {
        return 0;
    }
}
```